# I need to convert my input date ( 2020-12-03T15:20:50.000Z) to YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format using NiFi

Tags: json, datetime, apache-nifi

I need to convert my input date in the format **2020-12-03T15:20:50.000Z** to **YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS** format. The incoming input is JSON and am trying to insert them into DB2.

So my nifi flow is like this ==> ConvertJSONtoSQL --> UpdateAttribute --> PutSQL

I tried this in Update Attribute :

```
Property   
sql.args.31.value 

Value 
${sql.args.31.value:toDate("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss:SSS'Z'"):toNumber():format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")}
```

But this is not working and instead throwing error:

[image]

Comment: you have `.000Z` in value and trying to parse it as `:000Z`. just change parsing format to `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'`

Comment: Yes I figured after I posted it, such a silly mistake. Thank you very much for your prompt response. I appreciate it greatly. @daggett